# My custom adapter for my recycler view keeps crashing because it is null even though I have initialized it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This is an issue that I have been having for days and I have tried many solutions.

With my latest solution it keeps crashing.

This is my `UserListRecycler` class - the main class

```
public class UserListRecycler extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static UserAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<UserInfo> list;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlistGUI, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reUsers);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        // Instantiate new adapter here
        adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        // Sets the adapter here
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        populateRecyclerList();
    }


    public void populateList(){
        PopulateUsers userList = new PopulateUsers(list, adapter, recyclerView);
        userList.execute();
    }
}
```

This is my `PopulateUsers` class - where details from my server are retrieve via `REST`

```
public class PopulateUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    static ArrayList<UserInfo> list;
    UserAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

public PopulateUsers(ArrayList<UserInfo> list, UserAdapter adapter, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>(); 
    this.adapter = new UserAdapter();
    this.list = list;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // `REST` Activity happens here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    try {
        // IT CRASHES HERE, BUT IF I INSTANTIATE A NEW LIST, 
        // THEN THIS ERROR GOES AND NOTHING IS DISPLAYED
        list.clear();  
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String forename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("forename");
            String surname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("surname");
            String nationality = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nationality");
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(forename, surname, nationality);
            list.add(userInfo);
        }
        // THIS LINE BELOW IS THE BIGGEST CULPRIT. IT HAS BEEN A HUGE HEADACHE
        // I EVEN TRIED THIS: adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
        // AND IT STILL CRASHES
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The `adapter` is `NULL` but how can it be friggin `NULL` if I have initialised it!

It keeps crashing when I call the `populateList()` method in another `AsyncTask` class - see below:

```
public class RecommendUsers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // REST stuff happens here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String postData) {
        // The following line invokes the instance of `PopulateUserList` and crashes.
        // This is the culprit line
        populateList();
    }
}
```

This is the `stack trace`:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lukasz.usersapp.PopulateUsers.onPostExecute(PopulateUsers.java:67)
            at lukasz.usersapp.PopulateUsers.onPostExecute(PopulateUsers.java:27)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Basically it crashes at `list.clear()`, but that is not an issue - I can fix, but the follow up - the `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)` is the one that is giving me a big headache. Literally driving me bonkers!!!

Would appreciate some support or solutions

EDIT: I have initialised the `list` and `adapter` in the `PopulateUsers` class and it still crashes

Comment: Your class PopulateUsers has a constructor by name PopulatePodcastList. Also, where are you calling execute() method on the asynctasks?

Comment: Your adapter in PopulateUsers is null, as I dont see it initialised anywhere in that class. You have init an adapter in UserListRecycler, but PopulateUsers doesnt have access to that does it?

Comment: Hi, so how do I rectify this mess or bug?

Comment: Your constructor should be the same name as the name of the class. Also, initialize the adapter in the actual class you want to use it in.

Comment: @TechnoBlahble and it still crashes, please see edited POST

Comment: I see you changed the constructor, but the adapter is still null. Also, where are you initializing an object for PopulateUsers so that you can pass the adapter as an argument ?

Comment: @TechnoBlahble in the `populateList()` method

Comment: @TechnoBlahble I modified my constructor so I have initialised them

Comment: It keeps crashing on `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` - apparently it is `NULL` even though I have initialised it

Comment: Is it the `recyclerview` giving the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104907/discussion-between-technoblahble-and-lukazs-pioetrszci).

Answer (score 0):

try to set the adapter of the RecyclerView after populating your list.

Comment: Sorry, where would I do that?

Comment: Because at the moment I set the adapter in the `AsyncTask` class

Comment: It is something to do with the `recyclerView` itself, I think. I am passing it, but I don't think it is being initialised

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your constructor to this -

```
public PopulateUsers(ArrayList<UserInfo> list, UserAdapter adapter, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>(); 
    this.adapter = new UserAdapter();
    this.list = list;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}
```

Comment: I did and it still crashes :(

Comment: It is something to do with the `recyclerView` itself, I think. I am passing it, but I don't think it is being initialised

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
list = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
    list.add("your value");
    list.add("your another value");
    adapter = new MusicRecyclerAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It is something to do with the `recyclerView` itself, I think. I am passing it, but I don't think it is being initialised

Comment: man, i think i found the answear, is obvious: the "onStart" is called before the "onCreateView", so the list does not exist. You have to initialize your list inside the "onStart" or do something that initialize it

Comment: what are you on about??? `onStart` is called AFTER `onCreateView`. `onStart` is defined after `onCreateView` as seen in my code in the OP